# Why does a command work from shell, but not from the applications menu?

Tags: menu, sudo, command-line

I'm trying to add a command to my applications menu:

[image]

But when I select it from the applications menu, it doesn't do anything.

When I run that same command from the shell, however, it runs fine. Why?

(Also, why does pycharm need sudo priviledges?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always use gksudo when you run graphical applications. Not only does it provide you with a prompt so you can enter your password, but it also uses some variables that are important.

I have no idea why or if PyCharm requires root privileges. It's easier to provide a good answer if you provide more details.

Comment: `gksudo` did the trick. thanks! what more details do you need though? when I run it without sudo it says `bash: /usr/local/bin/charm: Permission denied`

Comment: @Mark: You should mark the solution as accepted solution, if it solves your problem, and there is no reason, to wait for a better solution.

Comment: @user unknown: thanks tips. i was waiting a bit to see if anyone could answer the "why does pycharm need sudo" bit, but i guess that deserves a second question/asked elsewhere anyway.

Comment: I don't know how you installed the application. It might have been a packaging error or something or there might be real reasons why it needs root privileges. I don't know that application well enough to say. I suggest you open a new question for that and provide everything you can. Version of Ubuntu, how you installed PyCharm, where you got it from, which version of it you installed, etc.